# Getting error when trying to create view in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW fq0clnt100.sv_0material_test AS 
 SELECT a.matnr, a.ersda, a.ernam, a.laeda, a.aenam, a.vpsta, a.pstat, a.lvorm, a.mtart, a.mbrsh, a.matkl, a.bismt, a.meins, a.bstme, a.zeinr, a.zeiar, a.zeivr, a.zeifo, a.aeszn, a.blatt, a.blanz, a.ferth, a.formt, a.groes, a.wrkst, a.normt, a.labor, a.ekwsl, a.brgew, a.ntgew, a.gewei, a.volum, a.voleh, a.behvo, a.raube, a.tempb, a.disst, a.tragr, a.stoff, a.spart, a.kunnr, a.eannr, a.wesch, a.bwvor, a.bwscl, a.saiso, a.etiar, a.etifo, a.entar, a.ean11, a.numtp, a.laeng, a.breit, a.hoehe, a.meabm, a.prdha, a.aeklk, a.cadkz, a.qmpur, a.ergew, a.ergei, a.ervol, a.ervoe, a.gewto, a.volto, a.vabme, a.kzrev, a.kzkfg, a.xchpf, a.vhart, a.fuelg, a.stfak, a.magrv, a.begru, a.datab, a.liqdt, a.saisj, a.plgtp, a.mlgut, a.extwg, a.satnr, a.attyp, a.kzkup, a.kznfm, a.pmata, a.mstae, a.mstav, a.mstde, a.mstdv, a.taklv, a.rbnrm, a.mhdrz, a.mhdhb, a.mhdlp, a.inhme, a.inhal, a.vpreh, a.etiag, a.inhbr, a.cmeth, a.cuobf, a.kzumw, a.kosch, a.sprof, a.nrfhg, a.mfrpn, a.mfrnr, a.bmatn, a.mprof, a.kzwsm, a.saity, a.profl, a.ihivi, a.iloos, a.serlv, a.kzgvh, a.xgchp, a.kzeff, a.compl, a.iprkz, a.rdmhd, a.przus, a.mtpos_mara, a.bflme, a.zzekgrp, a."class", a.zzgfklm, a.evers, a.zzsubmt, a.zzherst, a.zzartnum, a.changemode, a.entitycounter, a.loadtime, b.txtmd, c.mm_materialg013
   FROM fq0clnt100.st_0material_attr a
   LEFT JOIN fq0clnt100.st_0material_text b ON a.matnr::text = b.matnr::text AND b.spras::text = 'E'::character varying::text
   LEFT JOIN fq0clnt100.st_1cl_omat001 c ON a.matnr::text = c.matnr::text;
   LEFT JOIN arriva_group.st_sa_mat_mapping_sap d on  a.matnr like '%'||d.material ;
```

> Error : Syntax error at or near "Left"( for last row only)

Comment: I don't know redshift, but that semicolon at the end of the 2nd left join is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the semicolon in line 5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW fq0clnt100.sv_0material_test AS 
SELECT a.matnr, a.ersda, a.ernam, a.laeda, a.aenam, a.vpsta, a.pstat, a.lvorm, a.mtart, a.mbrsh, a.matkl, a.bismt, a.meins, a.bstme, a.zeinr, a.zeiar, a.zeivr, a.zeifo, a.aeszn, a.blatt, a.blanz, a.ferth, a.formt, a.groes, a.wrkst, a.normt, a.labor, a.ekwsl, a.brgew, a.ntgew, a.gewei, a.volum, a.voleh, a.behvo, a.raube, a.tempb, a.disst, a.tragr, a.stoff, a.spart, a.kunnr, a.eannr, a.wesch, a.bwvor, a.bwscl, a.saiso, a.etiar, a.etifo, a.entar, a.ean11, a.numtp, a.laeng, a.breit, a.hoehe, a.meabm, a.prdha, a.aeklk, a.cadkz, a.qmpur, a.ergew, a.ergei, a.ervol, a.ervoe, a.gewto, a.volto, a.vabme, a.kzrev, a.kzkfg, a.xchpf, a.vhart, a.fuelg, a.stfak, a.magrv, a.begru, a.datab, a.liqdt, a.saisj, a.plgtp, a.mlgut, a.extwg, a.satnr, a.attyp, a.kzkup, a.kznfm, a.pmata, a.mstae, a.mstav, a.mstde, a.mstdv, a.taklv, a.rbnrm, a.mhdrz, a.mhdhb, a.mhdlp, a.inhme, a.inhal, a.vpreh, a.etiag, a.inhbr, a.cmeth, a.cuobf, a.kzumw, a.kosch, a.sprof, a.nrfhg, a.mfrpn, a.mfrnr, a.bmatn, a.mprof, a.kzwsm, a.saity, a.profl, a.ihivi, a.iloos, a.serlv, a.kzgvh, a.xgchp, a.kzeff, a.compl, a.iprkz, a.rdmhd, a.przus, a.mtpos_mara, a.bflme, a.zzekgrp, a."class", a.zzgfklm, a.evers, a.zzsubmt, a.zzherst, a.zzartnum, a.changemode, a.entitycounter, a.loadtime, b.txtmd, c.mm_materialg013
FROM fq0clnt100.st_0material_attr a
LEFT JOIN fq0clnt100.st_0material_text b ON a.matnr::text = b.matnr::text AND b.spras::text = 'E'::character varying::text
LEFT JOIN fq0clnt100.st_1cl_omat001 c ON a.matnr::text = c.matnr::text
LEFT JOIN arriva_group.st_sa_mat_mapping_sap d on  a.matnr like '%'||d.material ;
```